# Evaluate $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}f\left(x+\dfrac1x\right)\cdot\dfrac{\log x}{x}\;\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration

The answer is supposed to be an integer, but I don’t understand how the function $f$ is to be solved. What should be the first step?

Comment: You didn't write your hypothesis on $f$, please be more precise when posting a question.

Comment: This is not true for all $f$. For instance let $f(x)=x$ and the integral diverges.

Comment: @Gauge_name exactly, there is no information given about $f$

Comment: This integral converges when $f(x) \sim \frac{1}{x^p}, p>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are going to prove that

if  $\;\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}f\left(x+\dfrac1x\right)\cdot\dfrac{\log x}{x}\;\mathrm{d}x\;$ converges, then its value is $\;0\;.$

**Proof**:

By letting $\;t=\dfrac1x\;,$ we get that

$\;\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}f\left(x+\dfrac1x\right)\cdot\dfrac{\log x}{x}\;\mathrm{d}x=\displaystyle\int_{\infty}^0f\left(\dfrac1t+t\right)\big(-t\log t\big)\left(-\dfrac1{t^2}\right)\mathrm{d}t=$

$=-\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}f\left(t+\dfrac1t\right)\cdot\dfrac{\log t}{t}\;\mathrm{d}t=-\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}f\left(x+\dfrac1x\right)\cdot\dfrac{\log x}{x}\;\mathrm{d}x\;.$

Hence,

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}f\left(x+\dfrac1x\right)\cdot\dfrac{\log x}{x}\;\mathrm{d}x=-\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}f\left(x+\dfrac1x\right)\cdot\dfrac{\log x}{x}\;\mathrm{d}x\;,$

consequently,

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}f\left(x+\dfrac1x\right)\cdot\dfrac{\log x}{x}\;\mathrm{d}x=0\;.$